# adding extra files to vb.net project

Tags: vb.net, publish

I am trying to add some 'supporting' files to my project in VB.NET Express 2012. These files are additional files that are not really part of VB.NET such as RTF files which are templates for reports etc. There is also some text based template files, that will get modified as part of the execution of my program.

What I have done:

- I have added these to the project (i.e. they appear in the Solution
  Explorer under the project)
- I have set the 'Copy to Output Directory' of each of the files to
  "Copy Always" in the properties window.

When I publish the project and re-install it, none of these files are included.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From build action you should select "content"